# Reload SCSF application

Tags: c#, scsf

I am using SCSF to define a framework of a set of loosely coupled applications and services. The profilecatalog.xml file describes, which plugins should be loaded and also the dependency to the services. This is the standard procedure and is operating well.

However, I would like to enable the possibility to load a plugin at runtime. I have some plugins, which take some time to load. And this plugins are used rarely. So I think to enable the possibility to load this plugins at runtime, only when needed (User clicks on the item). 
It is of course possible to write the plugins in a way, that does not slow down the starting time of the framework. But I am not responsible for any plugin, so I try to solve this issue from the framework by not loading any plugin.

Comment: You might want to remind people what SCSF is!

Comment: You are right. I could have extended the description a bit. But I do not know, if one could help me, not knowing Smart Client Software Factory much.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically load your SCSF modules using techniques outlined in these articles:

1. http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2006/02/27/cabmodulesondemand/
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mszcool/archive/2005/12/20/505976.aspx
3. http://smartclient.codeplex.com/discussions/222221

One limitation that you might run into is that modules cannot be "unloaded" dynamically.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I will investigae the articles. I do know that unloading is another story. But I am fine with this restriction. I just want to load them. I upvote your post. If I find a suitable answer, I will check the acceptance as well. Thanks!

Comment: The first links looks exactly to what I am searching. However, the link to the source code is unfortunately broken. The sample code would be very nice to see.

Comment: The example in the first link talks about modifying default SCSF solution files.  If you are working with an existing solution you should be able to follow it and make the same modifications in your project.  There are already comments in the link that are a couple years old which request for a re-upload of a the sample so I wouldn't hold my breath for it.  If you run into further issues you can post them here and I will do my best to help.